# RuntimeError: class '__torch__.torch_sparse.tensor.SparseTensor' already defined

Tags: python, pytorch

My OS is unbantu and my graphics card is Tesla P100 and  CUDA Version: 10.1

[image: 1]

python is 3.8 pytorch 1.8.1
After I installed pyg according to pyg's tutorial

```
pip install torch-scatter torch-sparse torch-cluster torch-spline-conv torch-geometric -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-1.8.0+cu101.html
```

but when from torch_geometric.data import Data

> > > from torch_geometric.data import Data
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > File "", line 1, in 
> > > File "/home/huxiao/anaconda3/envs/pyg-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch_geometric/**init**.py", line 4, in 
> > > import torch_geometric.data
> > > File "/home/huxiao/anaconda3/envs/pyg-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch_geometric/data/**init**.py", line 1, in 
> > > from .data import Data
> > > File "/home/huxiao/anaconda3/envs/pyg-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch_geometric/data/data.py", line 9, in 
> > > from torch_sparse import SparseTensor
> > > File "/home/huxiao/anaconda3/envs/pyg-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch_sparse/**init**.py", line 41, in 
> > > from .tensor import SparseTensor  # noqa
> > > File "/home/huxiao/anaconda3/envs/pyg-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch_sparse/tensor.py", line 13, in 
> > > class SparseTensor(object):
> > > File "/home/huxiao/anaconda3/envs/pyg-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/jit/_script.py", line 974, in script
> > > _compile_and_register_class(obj, _rcb, qualified_name)
> > > File "/home/huxiao/anaconda3/envs/pyg-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/jit/_script.py", line 67, in _compile_and_register_class
> > > torch._C._jit_script_class_compile(qualified_name, ast, defaults, rcb)
> > > RuntimeError: class '**torch**.torch_sparse.tensor.SparseTensor' already defined.
> > > [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVDHu.png)

what should i do now？